# How to refactor the code safely with refactor tools?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, refactoring

Original Java code:

```
public int test() {
    int total = 100;
    if (new Random().nextInt(2) < 1) {
        total += 1;
    } else {
        total -= 2;
    }
    return total;
}
```

The expected code after refactor:

```
public int test() {
    return 100 + randomChange();
}

private int randomChange() {
    return new Random().nextInt(2) < 1 ? 1 : -2;
}
```

I can change the code manually, but I want to reply on IDE's refactor tools (e.g. IDEA or eclipse). Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do it.

Is it possible to refactor the code all by tools and without break it manually?

Comment: I wouldn't consider splitting a 7-line method into two methods and changing `if` to a ternary expression - as refactoring...

Comment: Why do you expect someone would provide a refactor tool to make this specific change?  There's no magic "make the code the way I expect" tool, and if there was, you (and most of us) would be out of a job.

Comment: @alfasin, consider this is a simplified sample

Comment: @JimGarrison, eclipse and IDEA have provided lot of refactor tools, my question is about how to use them to get my goal

Comment: then in the end you want to do some other refactoring? then how us telling you how to do *this* would help you? Also if you want to do even more complex refactoring then you should do it manually, don't trust the tool so much.

Comment: I want to figure out what kinds of refactoring tools can help, and reply on them as much as possible

Comment: @alfasin, please explain why not. For me  the second code is more clean (at least the test method), so its a good refactoring. Even 7 line methods should be refactored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight this:

```
if (new Random().nextInt(2) < 1) {
    total += 1;
} else {
    total -= 2;
}
```

**Extract method:** And use **extract method** (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for Eclipse and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for Intellij iirc, but double check that!). Still you need to do some manual refactoring as this by default will want you to pass "total" as an argument and return a changed value.

**If/else -> ternary:** There *are* ways to change the if/else statement to ternary operators but they are not provided by the IDE but by 3rd party plugins for instance for Eclipse this should be of [help](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spartan-refactoring#.UmN7c5SSDQ8).

**Local var -> return statement:** as for the "total" variable I'm not aware of any plugins that would do that and Eclipse/Intellij don't have such an option (at least I'm not aware of one). They can do it the other way around with extract local variable.

@Downvoter: this is the closest you can get with current refactoring tools. As it was mentioned in the comment section there is no magical "read my mind" button.

Comment: First, thank you, and I'm not the downvoter :) I can get this result but I want to if I can do more with them.

Comment: @Freewind: you can check my updated message. You can cope with if/else using plugins. For the "substitute variable with return" I'm afraid it's not supported. There might be some plugins, though.

Comment: that's a useful advice!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to refactor that on eclipse, which wouldn't actually give the exact code you want:

1. Select the `if-else` block.
2. Right-click, and go to "refactor"
3. Go to option - "Extract Method"
4. Give a method name - "randomChange". You will see that it passes the `total` as parameter to the method.
5. Click "OK".

Your code will be rafactored to this:

```
public int test() {
    int total = 100;
    total = randomChange(total);
    return total;
}

private int randomChange(int total) {
    if (new Random().nextInt(2) < 1) {
        total += 1;
    } else {
        total -= 2;
    }
    return total;
}
```

However, I don't think there is a way to refactor the `if-else` blocks into conditional.

Comment: I don't get it who's downvoting this stuff... This is the closes you can get with refactoring tools...

Comment: @RohitJain, thank you, I've refactored the code exactly like the result in your answer. But I hope I can remove the `total` parameter from `randomChange` method. Is it possible?

Comment: @Freewind I can't find a way to achieve that.

Comment: @RohitJain, thank you so much and it's enough for me to know it